# CScript to CPubKey or derive CPubKey from CScript

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Please can someone advise if it is possible to derive the CPubKey from a CSript object? Provided i get it up with an address before hand,

I can use numerous functions to attain all the info from the CPubKey using functions, but can you make a CPubKey from a CSript?

Or are they too much chalk and cheese?

Thank you,

EDIT:
Following the first answer I've tried the below to no joy. The script returns totally empty:

> ```
> CScript scriptPubKey1;
> CBitcoinAddress address("L4VPgtoBtuxsYMgyrRvQRadSV1Y139TDfd");
> scriptPubKey1.SetDestination(address.Get());
>
> CScript::const_iterator it = scriptPubKey1.begin(); // or specifically, the location of the pubkey in the CScript object
> opcodetype opcode;
> std::vector<unsigned char> data;
> scriptPubKey1.GetOp(it, opcode, data); // data now contains the byte vector
>
> CPubKey pubkey3 = CPubKey(data);
> ```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Extract the key used in a script? Or deterministically randomly generate a key from the script? Do you want any relation between who can spend the script and who can spend the key?

Comment: I want to generate a pubkey in code based on an address. Allowing me to use this pubkey in transactions later on. A roundabout way of doing things but it works with what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @LeosSire You cannot get the public key from an address because addresses are either pubkey hash (`p2pkh`) or script hashes (`p2sh`) and you cannot reverse a hash.

Comment: @LeosSire I understand you want a "pubkey based on an address". But what does that mean? What are you trying to do? I have a feeling there is either an alternative solution to your problem, or an easier way of formulating it? What properties do you want that pubkey to have?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I believe you can construct a `CPubKey` from a byte vector extracted from the `CScript` `script` like:

```
CScript::const_iterator it = script.begin(); // or specifically, the location of the pubkey in the CScript object
opcodetype opcode;
valtype data;

script.GetOp(iterator, opcode, data); // data now contains the byte vector
CPubKey pubKey = CPubKey(data);
```